# Any solutions for this? Values aren't adding up

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make like a change calculator but it always prints out only 1 quarter and the rest are 0. I don't really get how to fix it and I changed some things but the end result is the same. Any solutions?

```
Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
    double c = 0;
    double quarter = 0;
    double dime = 0;
    double nickel = 0;
    double penny = 0;

    System.out.println("How much change?");
    c = e.nextDouble();

    while(c > 0.50) {
        quarter =+ 1;
        c =- .50;
    }
    while( c > 0.10) {
        dime =+ 1;
        c =- .10;
    }
    while(c > 0.05) {
        nickel =+ 1;
        c =- .5;
    }
    while(c > 0.01) {
        penny =+ 1;
        c =- 0.01;
    }

    System.out.println("You need " + quarter + " quarters");
    System.out.println("You need " + dime + " dimes");
    System.out.println("You need " + nickel + " nickels");
    System.out.println("You need " + penny + " pennies");
```

So what it prints out is like 1 quarter, 0 dime, 0 nickel, 0 penny
Any fixes so it can actually work? EDIT: I tried c = c - .5 it does add but the information is false

Comment: For quarter also change 0.50 to 0.25 :)

Comment: Quarters are 25 cents, not 50

Comment: @Zymus Oh my bad lol, I didn't notice and with the other answers it worked, thanks.

Comment: @INeedHelp It may appear to be fixed, but in fact your code is still broken. Google "is floating point math broken?".

Answer (score 0):

all your =+ should be +=

```
quarter =+ 1;
quarter += 1;
```

also the =- ...

In the end the code would look like :

```
while(c > 0.50) {
    quarter += 1;
    c -= .50;
}
while( c > 0.10) {
    dime += 1;
    c -= .10;
}
while(c > 0.05) {
    nickel += 1;
    c -= .5;
}
while(c > 0.01) {
    penny += 1;
    c -= 0.01;
}
```

also quarters are 25 cents not 50

Comment: @INeedHelp did you change the =- to -= too ?

Answer (score 0):

Your operators are wrong.

Change **=+** & **=-** to **+=** & **-=**.